# How to make a message saying the bot cant dm?

Tags: python, discord

Hello I would like to make a error message to have the bot send when the user has their DMs off. What would be the error message name?

I have the code below for wrong permissions; I just need the error message name to change it.

```
@ban.error
async def ban(ctx, error):
   if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
         await ctx.send("You dont have premissions to run this command")
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a way to send an error through that process, so doing `try: except:` should work similarly.

```
try:
    # Code to attempt to dm user
except:
    await ctx.send("Couldn't DM this user.")
```